# Set orientation of volume indicator for iPhone glES game

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, orientation, volume, indicator

I'm subclassing UIView using the standard EAGLView framework.  When I detect orientation changes, I just add a rotation to my OpenGL stack.  However, when the user adjusts the volume using the physical iPhone buttons, the volume indicator is (naturally) not rotated by the GL stack.
  How do I rotate the volume indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all keyed off of the `UIApplication.statusBarOrientation` property, which you can set.